# Spring + OpenFeign: POST Results in NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka, openfeign

I've been struggling with this for a while now. In short, the problem is whenever I make a `POST` request using OpenFeign I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

First, I generated my `build.gradle` directly from Spring Initializr including Eureka Discovery Client, Hystrix, Lombok, OpenFeign and Spring Reactive Web:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example.feign'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR1")
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'

    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Then, I created my `main` method:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;

@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
public class FeignApplication {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FeignApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then, my Feign proxy:

```java
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import uk.ac.warwick.wt.feign.dto.EchoRequest;
import uk.ac.warwick.wt.feign.dto.EchoResponse;

@FeignClient("echo-service")
public interface EchoProxy {
    @PostMapping(value = "/echo", consumes = "application/json")
    EchoResponse postEcho(@RequestBody EchoRequest echoRequest);
}
```

Where `echo-service` is a simple echo application that takes a `EchoRequest` DTO and returns an `EchoResponse` DTO.

```java
import lombok.*;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class EchoRequest {
    private String message;
}
```

`EchoResponse` is similar. Then I wrote the following service:

```java
@Service
public class EchoService {
    @Autowired
    private EchoProxy echoProxy;

    public String postEcho(String message) {
        return echoProxy.postEcho(new EchoRequest(message)).getMessage();
    }
}
```

Finally, I wrote a controller:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
import uk.ac.warwick.wt.feign.dto.FeignRequest;
import uk.ac.warwick.wt.feign.dto.FeignResponse;
import uk.ac.warwick.wt.feign.service.EchoService;

@RestController
@RestControllerAdvice
public class FeignController {
    @Autowired
    private EchoService echoService;

    @PostMapping("/feign")
    public FeignResponse postFeign(@RequestBody FeignRequest request) {
        return new FeignResponse(echoService.postEcho(request.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

Where `FeignRequest` is as simple as:

```java
import lombok.*;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class FeignRequest {
    private String message;
}
```

`FeignResponse` is similar.

Whenever I make the following `POST` call to the service:

```
{
    "message": "Hello, world!"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
feign.codec.EncodeException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$BuildEncodedTemplateFromArgs.resolve(ReflectiveFeign.java:376) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ? HTTP POST "/feign" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$BuildEncodedTemplateFromArgs.resolve(ReflectiveFeign.java:376) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$BuildTemplateByResolvingArgs.create(ReflectiveFeign.java:224) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:75) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.postEcho(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.example.feign.service.EchoService.postEcho(EchoService.java:14) ~[main/:na]
        at com.example.feign.controller.FeignController.postFeign(FeignController.java:20) ~[main/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:147) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) [reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1630) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:247) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:329) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1630) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144) [reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:330) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1630) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:209) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:367) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:363) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:461) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:89) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:211) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:326) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:300) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getObject(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringEncoder.encode(SpringEncoder.java:95) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$BuildEncodedTemplateFromArgs.resolve(ReflectiveFeign.java:372) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$BuildTemplateByResolvingArgs.create(ReflectiveFeign.java:224) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:75) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.postEcho(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.feign.service.EchoService.postEcho(EchoService.java:14) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.feign.controller.FeignController.postFeign(FeignController.java:20) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:147) ~[spring-webflux-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) [reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1630) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:247) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:329) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1630) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144) [reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:330) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1630) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:209) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:367) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:363) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:461) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:89) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:211) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:326) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:300) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OpenFeign is not compatible with WebFlux. If you use WebFlux you have to provide your own `Encoder` and `Decoder`, as in:

```java
import feign.codec.Decoder;
import feign.codec.Encoder;
import feign.jackson.JacksonDecoder;
import feign.jackson.JacksonEncoder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class FeignConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Decoder decoder() {
        return new JacksonDecoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public Encoder encoder() {
        return new JacksonEncoder();
    }
}
```

Also, notice that you can't return a `Mono` from a `FeignClient`. So if you need a `Mono` you have to create it in your service.

```java
public Mono<String> postEcho(String message) {
    return Mono.just(echoProxy.postEcho(new EchoRequest(message)).getMessage());
}
```

Comment: In addition to that -in my case- I had to add the below dependency for JacksonDecoder/JacksonEncoder

<dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>9.7.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Also, add to feign interface, `@FeignClient(name = "microService", url = "http://localhost:8080", configuration = MicroServiceConfig.class)`

Answer (score 0):

I solved by :

```
@Configuration
public class FeignResponseDecoderConfig {
    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder() {

        ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters = () -> {
            HttpMessageConverters converters = new HttpMessageConverters();
            return converters;
        };
        return new SpringDecoder(messageConverters);
    }
}
```